# Duals of modules over algebras

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules

Suppose $A$ is an associative and commutative $\mathbb{R}$-algebra with unit 
$1_A$ and $M$ is an $A$-module. Let's write $\cdot_A:A\times M\to M$ for the 
$A$-scalar multiplication on $M$.

1.) It follows that $M$ is naturally a $\mathbb{R}$-vector space with scalar
multiplication 
$$\cdot_{\mathbb{R}}:\mathbb{R}\times M\to M;(\lambda,x)\mapsto (\lambda\cdot_{\mathbb{R}} 1_A)\cdot_A x$$

2.) We can define the $A$-dual module $M^\vee:=\operatorname{Hom}_A(M,A)$ of $M$ as well as the $\mathbb{R}$-dual vector space $M^*:=\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{R}}(M,\mathbb{R})$.

---

Now the question is

> Is there an injective set-map
>   $$M^*\to M^\vee$$

Comment: Of course not. If $M \neq 0$, we have $M^* \neq 0$, but $M^\vee=0$ may happen. Maybe you want to ask for something else?

Comment: Ah you are right. I see the problem now. I think I'm not that fluent in general module theory. Thanks ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the very simple case of $\def\R{\mathbb{R}}\def\C{\mathbb{C}}A=\mathbb{C}$ and take $M=\mathbb{C}$. There *are* $\R$-linear isomorphisms $\def\Hom{\operatorname{Hom}}\C^*=\Hom_{\R}(\C,\R)\to\C=\Hom_{\C}(\C,\C)$, but they depend on the choice of a basis on $\C$ (over $\R$).

Consider also the fact that one can have $\Hom_A(M,A)=0$ without $M$ being the zero module.

From the ring morphism $\R\to A$ you can get an $\R$-linear morphism
$$
\Hom_{\R}(M,\R)\to\Hom_{\R}(M,A)
$$
but there's no reason why its image should be contained in $\Hom_A(M,A)$.